# Can a webserver redirect https requests to another webserver's http?

Tags: redirect, webserver

I'm using a package that connects to a database and presents the database schema as APIs.  The package provides the service as a webserver.  I can choose to use any port, but it's still HTTP.  Even if I run it with port 443, requests must be in the form of http://mydomain:443/

I may be forced to provide the service through SSL.  Is it possible to run a webserver which would redirect HTTPS requests to redirect to the package running HTTP on port 80, with the outgoing traffic going back through the webserver to clients as SSL?  Essentially, I need some kind of wrapper around the existing app to provide SSL.

If such a thing is possible, which webserver would be the best choice and easiest to administer on Linux?